# What is a word for being dead yet alive at the same time

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say that Limbo is real. This is a place where you're in a state of being alive and dead at the same time. What would this state of life/death be called?

Comment: Um. The state would be called *limbo*. What am I missing here?

Comment: I would suggest **couch potato** or **Live TV Audience** as possibilities.

Comment: I think that’s called ***mostly dead***   “*There's a big difference between mostly dead and all dead. Mostly dead is slightly alive. With all dead, well, with all dead there's usually only one thing you can do.*” - *Miracle Max*

Answer (score 3):

Probably not what you are seeking, but in relation to Schrödinger's famous cat, which is both alive and dead at the same time, this is called '[quantum superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat)':

> The scenario presents a cat that may be simultaneously both alive and dead, a state known as a **quantum superposition**
>
> *www.wikipedia.org*

Answer (score 1):

One example with related meaning, although probably not what you had in mind, is **zombie**. From an attributive perspective, the words **transient** and **transitory** come to mind. On the other hand, the scenario you have mentioned does not really sound like it involves a person being "alive" at all. Assuming you mean Limbo as in Purgatory, and given that there is a soul separate from the body, the soul would be the thing in Limbo -- not the body. When we speak of life and death, are we not talking about the body?

As for whether a person in Limbo can do bodily activities, that is not really an appropriate question on the English section of Stack Exchange. That is not a question of language but of religion or mythology.

Comment: Limbo is the first level of Hell, separate from Purgatory, according to Dante's interpretation.

Comment: @Kit -- Yeah, I remember that now. Not everyone has had the pleasure of traversing the underworld without actually dying.